# bind window pixmap to texture using GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, xlib, glx

i want to know how to bind a window pixmap to a OpenGL Texture using the GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap extension , i don't get  it to work, this is my code:

```
     const int pixmap_config[] = {
        GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA_EXT, True,
        GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PIXMAP_BIT,
        GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_TARGETS_EXT, GLX_TEXTURE_2D_BIT_EXT,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, False,
        GLX_Y_INVERTED_EXT, GLX_DONT_CARE,
        None
    };

    const int pixmap_attribs[] = {
        GLX_TEXTURE_TARGET_EXT, GLX_TEXTURE_2D_EXT,
        GLX_TEXTURE_FORMAT_EXT, GLX_TEXTURE_FORMAT_RGB_EXT,
        None
    };

    GLXFBConfig * configs = 0;
    GLXPixmap glxpixmap = 0;
    Pixmap pixmap;
    GLuint texture_id;

    int c=0;
    configs = glXChooseFBConfig(display, 0, pixmap_config, &c);

    pixmap = XCompositeNameWindowPixmap (display, desktop);

    cout<<"Pixmap id"<<pixmap<<endl;

    glxpixmap = glXCreatePixmap(display, configs[0], pixmap, pixmap_attribs);

    cout <<"glxpixmap id"<<glxpixmap<<endl;
    if(glxpixmap){
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
        glXBindTexImageEXT(display, glxpixmap, GLX_FRONT_EXT, NULL);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    }
```

this throw me a X error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (Composite)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

this happens in the line of `glXBindTexImageEXT(display, glxpixmap, GLX_FRONT_EXT, NULL);`. I tested it using an empty pixmap and works, but when i use `XCompositeNameWindowPixmap` this falls in that error, ¿what could be wrong in my code?

**Edit:**

I found using another code that using XCompositeNameWindowPixmap always returns a black image, maybe this can be happen because i am using ubuntu on a vmware player? i use the code of this entry:

[Qt with XComposite problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252179/qt-with-xcomposite-problem)

Comment: Is `desktop` visible when you call `XCompositeNameWindowPixmap`?

Comment: in this case the desktop is the XDefaultRootWindow, i suppose that the root window is always visible, Is that so?

Comment: Is your application in fullscreen mode? It would be worth checking if this matters imho.

Comment: no, i am trying to display the screenshot in a openGL GLUT window (500x500), this windows has as parent window an overlay window created using XCompositeGetOverlayWindow in the root window.

Comment: well, nevermind then.

Comment: you know another way for convert an screenshot to a opengl texture?, maybe glcopyteximage2d? but how to use it in real time?

Comment: Why aren't you using `XGrabServer`? Have a look at this [spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_from_pixmap.txt).

Comment: thanks, i use the code of your link too, and throw me the same error.

Comment: sorry, I reimplemented your program using the bits you provided, and get the same error. That GLX extention isn't finalized it appears, and maybe using it on the root window is the problem.

Comment: yeah the problem is using XCompositeNameWindowPixmap in the root window, so i'm trying to find how to get the desktop pixmap to an overlay window but i get a repetitive image so i dont get how to create a zoom in my desktop :/ like ezoom in compiz, i have the code but i don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and incomplete checklist:

- Is window whose pixmap you're trying to get visible?

  - In other words, is it mapped?
- Is window whose pixmap you're trying to get of type `InputOutput`?
- Did you redirect the root window using `xcb_composite_redirect_subwindows(..., XCB_COMPOSITE_REDIRECT_MANUAL);` (or the Xlib equivalent?)

  - Just creating an overlay is not enough.
  - Note, I have not tried redirecting individual windows nor did I try using `_AUTOMATIC`.
  - The need to do `xcb_composite_redirect_...` is hidden in the `GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap` spec.

Keep in mind: you *don't* want another compositor running, and *probably* not even another window manager. KWin, even with compositing disabled, breaks the current iteration of my toy compositor.

---

Unrelated to your specific error message, but a possible stumbling block: depending on your GPU's capabilities, you may have to use the `GL_NEAREST` texture filter for the min and mag filters.

Additional caveat for your setup: The overlay window will not let you interact the desktop, as it is an actual overlay. Common way to go around this problem is to use XFixes to punch a hole in your window AND in the overlay window (as far as the input/event system is concerned).